# UILabel is nil on runtime, works on simulator, but crashes on device

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift2, fatal-error, option-type

I'm learning Swift 2 and changing old Objective-C code to swift.

I just put a UILabel in the nib and connect it to the nib's Controller.

The code works on simulator (iOS 8.4 and iOS 9), but crashes on the device (iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s, both is iOS 8.4), and the crash info is: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Here's the related code:

code in my view controller:

```
var round: Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var nextRoundLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.nextRoundLabel.text = "\(self.round)"
    }
}
```

code of pushing the viewController:

```
    let rvc = RoundViewController()
    rvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl
    rvc.round = 1
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rvc, animated: true)
```

instances when error happens:

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning the project before building for the device. Alternatively try deleting the app from the device then run it again from Xcode. I've had issues in the past with storyboards/nibs not updating on device.

Comment: @SteveWilford I've tried cleaning, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: roundLabel != nextRoundLabel. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across same issue with iOS8.4. When you push a view controller you should specify the nib name. For this, override the init in RoundViewController.

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

And to instanciate the controller:

```
    let rvc = RoundViewController(nibName: "RoundViewController")
```

Comment: let rvc = RoundViewController(nibName: "RoundViewController",bundle: nil) You need to give bundle too.